# How do I notate the conditional combination of two sequences?

Tags: sequences-and-series, functions, algorithms, notation

Apologies for any incorrect usage of maths notation in my explanation. I am not a mathematician, I operate in the area of computer science. So some dumbed down explanation and pointing out which bits are confusing or which bits I get wrong would be very helpful.

So I have two sequences $E$ and $X$ and $|E| \le |X|$ (size of E is smaller than or equal to size of X). I want to be able to show that given a certain condition, the elements in $E$ replace certain elements in $X$.

So far I've tried to show that every element $e_j \in E$ has an associated index $i$ such that $f:E \to I, f(e_j) = i$. I then want to show that some function like $g(e_j)$ returns a true or false that determines if $e_j$ is going to replace $x_{f(e_j)}$ such that:

\begin{equation}x^{\prime}_{f(e_j)} = \begin{cases} e_j,& \text{if } g(e_j) = T\\ x_{f(e_j)} & \text{otherwise}  \end{cases}\end{equation}

I then want to also show that this process happens for all $e_j \in E$.

So the main questions are as follows:

1. Does my definition of function $f$ make sense and do I need to demonstrate that it is injective (i.e. no two $e_j$ can have the same $i$)?
2. How would I show that function $g$ returns a true or false?
3. Is using a function as a subscript valid since it returns an index?
4. To show that the process happens for all $e_j \in E$ should I put $\forall e_j \in E$ in front of the large equation above? Or is this unnecessary?
5. Is there any more appropriate language, or notation I could use that would have made this more clear and concise?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suggestions:

Avoid using capital letters to denote sequences such as $E$ and $X$, this is very non-usual, I read this as expectancy operator and random variable $X$. You can use as you did $e_j$ to be a sequence element, but and represent the sequence with a parenthesis coupled with a domain for the index such as $(e_j), \, j\leq j_{max}$.

Also, make the domain and image of your function more comprehensible by stating $I\subset \mathbb{N}$. But also try avoiding to introduce an $i$ symbol like this. I though it was the complex unit.

Mathematicians also don't usually think with boolean variables (that have TRUE=T or FALSE=F as their values). Speak in terms of 0 and 1, preferably. Think that statements are true or false in a logical sense.

Answering your questions:

1-I think I understood your point, but defining $f(e_j) = i$ makes me believe it is a constant function. If I understood correctly it is a mapping between $E$ and $I$.

2- Zero for false and one for true are an option, but this also would depend on how the function $g$ works.

3-Yes, it is perfectly valid.  Maybe you could define an auxiliary sequence defined as $b_k = f(e_j)$.

4- You could, but it would also need to be true. For instance you didn't specify $f$ to be [injective](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Injective_function) hence there could be $j\neq j'$ such that $f(e_j)-f(e_{j'})$, and a desfavoable matching condition for $g$.

5-Dont think there would be something much more concise, also for something to be "clear" is a rather subjective question. I can propose the definition below and you may draw ideias you like form it:

Let: $(a_n), n\leq n_{max}$ and $b_k, k\leq k_{max}$ with $n_{max}\leq k_{max}$.
Let $f(a_n)=f_n \in \mathbb{N}  $ and $g(a_n)\in {0,1}$ 
Let $d_m, m\leq k_{max}$, be constructed by:
$$
d_m = \left \{\begin{array}{cc} a_{m}, && \text{if} \, f_n=m \, \text{and} \, g(a_n) = 1   \\  b_m, &&  \text{otherwise}\end{array} \right.
$$

Comment: Thanks this was really helpful, I'll wait a little longer to accept to give others a chance. One question though, if I need to pass a whole sequence into a function for example, how should I notate that? So if I had some function f(x) which sums all elements of sequence x for example, do I just notate that as a lowercase letter (like I just did)?

Comment: Use an operator instead of a function (functions usually have very well defined arguments). Or maybe, use a simple variable like $A=\sum e_j$. Passing a sequence as an argument to a function is something that generally makes sense in programming, but not so much in mathematics.

Comment: Ah yes of course. Also, if I am defining multiple sequences that all have the same indices, do I need to express the range for each sequence? Or can I just do it once. By which I mean can I write $(a_i),i \leq n$ and $b_i$? Or do I need to write  $(a_i),i \leq n$ and $(b_i),i \leq n$?

Comment: If in both cases the index has the same range, it would be okay to define it just once, it is also easier on the eye if the sequences and the range are presented close by in the text (not in separate pages). But this is a matter of style.

Comment: Great thanks for that. An additional confusion from my perspective is that the $f(a_n)$ function in your proposed definition appears as if it must iterates through every $a_n$ testing if it is equal to $m$ to find the right $a$. This would be inefficient because you could instead copy $d_m = b_m$ and then simply iterate through assigning $d_{f_n} = \begin{cases} a_n & \text{if } g(a_n) = 1 \\ d_{f_n} & \text{otherwise } \end{cases}$ (which is what I have done in my work). However, does this notation make sense in maths? If not how could I make the iteration through $a_n$ more explicit?

Comment: Painting with thick brushes, I would say that Efficiency is a computation concern. Clarity and conciseness are the priority for mathematics. What you wrote does makes sense, but I personally avoid using functions for indexes. Also, this may leave room for someone not noticing that $f_n$ is a subscript, and read $df_n$ as a differential.